# A provided field name ("_LikeCount"and "_CommentCount") is not recognized Graph Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, ms-graph-client

Hi i am trying to sort the result of my query by _LikeCount or _CommentCount of the Site Pages however i always got "A Provided field is not recognize" , any help is appreciated why it cannot be seen.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{ID}/lists/Site Pages/items?$filter=fields/PromotedState eq 2&expand=fields($select=createdDateTime,BannerImageUrl,PromotedState,FileLeafRef,AuthorLookupId,Modified,_CommentCount,_LikeCount,Title,Description,LinkTitle)&$top=5&$orderby=fields/_LikeCount desc
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like LikeCount & CommentCount are complex/lookup fields.

Comment: @GaneshSanap any solution on this?